# Subscript out of range when removing element from set

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers, unordered-set

This is a simplification of an issue I encountered in another project.

Say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass() {
        std::cout << "MyClass constructed\n";
        Instances().insert(this);
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "MyClass destructed\n";
        Instances().erase(this);
    }

    static std::unordered_set<MyClass*>& Instances() {
        static std::unordered_set<MyClass*> _instances;
        return _instances;
    }

};
```

It has a static `unordered_set` that it uses for keeping track of existing instances of the class. When an instance is constructed, its address is added to the set; when an instance is destroyed, its address is removed from the set.

Now, I have another class that has a `vector` of `shared_ptr`s containing instances of `MyClass`:

```
struct InstanceContainer {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> instances;
};
```

A key point here is that there is a global instance of this class above `main`. This seems to be part of the problem, because declaring the class inside of `main` does not produce the issue.

Inside of `main`, I do the following (say the global instance of `InstanceContainer` is called `container`):

```
container.instances.emplace_back(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass));
```

Everything is fine until the program terminates, when I get a read access violation ("vector subscript out of range") when `Instances().erase(this)` is executed in `MyClass`'s destructor.

I thought that maybe I was attempting to erase the instance from `_instances` multiple times (hence the `cout`s)-- However, the contructor is only called once, and the destructor is only called once, as you'd expect. I found that when this happens, `_instances.size()` is equal to `0`. The weird thing is, it's equal to `0` before any calls to `erase`. Prior to anything being erased from the set, it's empty?!

My theory at this point is that this has to do with the order in which the objects are destructed as the program terminates. Perhaps the static `_instances` is being freed before the destructor for `MyClass` is called.

I was hoping someone would be able to shed some light on this, and confirm whether or not that's what's happening.

My workaround now is to check to see if `_instances.size()` is `0` before attempting to erase. Is this safe? If not, what else can I do?

If it matters, I'm using MSVC. Here's an [executable example](http://rextester.com/WAQDF70880).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens. That global variable of type `InstanceContainer` is constructed first, before `main` is entered. The function-static variable `_instances` is created later, when `Instances()` is called for the first time.

At program shutdown, destructors for these objects are called in the reverse order of construction. Therefore, `_instances` is destroyed first, and then `InstanceContainer`, which in turn destroys its vector of shared pointers, which in turn run `~MyClass` on all objects still in the vector, which in turn call `_instances.erase()` on already-destroyed `_instances`. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object whose lifetime has ended.

There are several ways you could work around this. One, you could ensure that `InstanceContainer::instances` is empty before `main` returns. No idea how feasible this is, as you've never explained what role `InstanceContainer` plays in your design.

Two, you could allocate `_instances` on the heap, and just leak it:

```
static std::unordered_set<MyClass*>& Instances() {
    static auto* _instances = new std::unordered_set<MyClass*>;
    return *_instances;
}
```

This will keep it alive through the destruction of global objects.

Three, you could put something like this before the definition of `InstanceContainer` global variable:

```
static int dummy = (MyClass::Instances(), 0);
```

This will ensure that `_instances` is created earlier, and therefore destroyed later.